# Assure one multiple dataframes stays inside the other one

Tags: python, openstreetmap

Code used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd

area = ox.geocode_to_gdf("Trafaria, Portugal")

tags_substation = {'power': 'substation'}
substation = ox.geometries_from_place("Trafaria, Portugal", tags_substation)
substation.plot()
print("Retrieved", len(substation), "substation objects")

tags_power_tower = {'power': 'tower'}
power_tower = ox.geometries_from_place("Trafaria, Portugal", tags_power_tower)
power_tower.plot()
print("Retrieved", len(power_tower), "power_tower objects")

tags_power_line = {'power': 'line'}
power_line = ox.geometries_from_place("Trafaria, Portugal", tags_power_line)

# perform a spatial join to keep only power lines that are within the area
power_line = power_line.drop(['index_right'], axis=1)
power_line = gpd.sjoin(power_line, area, op='intersects')
power_line.plot()

print("Retrieved", len(power_line), "power_line objects within the area")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
area.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="black")
substation.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="red", alpha=1)
power_tower.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="dimgray", alpha=1, markersize=10)
power_line.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="green", alpha=0.7)

plt.show()
```

Image below is when I have only the substations, power towers and the background.

[image]

This image are the power lines.

[image]

And this one is when I have everything together like the code I developed above.

[image]

I don't want this to happen, I want the power lines present but only inside "area" with the same escale as the first image, if it's out of that area/background I don't want to see it. How can I do that? I'm dealing (substation, power_tower,etc) with Dataframes variables.